# How to fix the error "Subject class type invalid."

Tags: java, pki, ca

I use java to code a CA module to create and sign the certificate. When I run my code, the error **"Subject class type invalid."** appeared, but in the destination folder I can get the two files: **rooca.crt** and **rootca.pfx**. The certificate contains the information I set. Maybe the code is result is right, but I still want to fix the error.

The details of the exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Subject class type invalid.
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.setSubject(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.set(Unknown Source)
at com.koal.Test.createIssueCert(Test.java:124)
at com.koal.Test.main(Test.java:353)
```

Part of my code:
[image]

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: Same with ISSUER in JDK1.8.0_144

Answer (score 11):

I faced a similar problem. This code is working well with Java 1.6 and fail with this exception while running on Java 1.8.

I can fix this issue by implementing [the following solution](https://github.com/wisdom-framework/wisdom/commit/15c4bb45a734ce07baf3fb461afbdb19c09254ab).

In fact, in Java 1.8, it seems that you do not have to encapsulate anymore the X500Name into CertificateSubjectName or CertificateIssuerName. You can store the X500Name object directly in the X509CertInfo instance.

Answer (score 4):

Change  this

```java
info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, new CertificateSubjectName(subject));
```

to

```java
info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, subject);
```

It worked for me.